# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 8383) after 10000ms

Tags: java, php, android, wampserver

I a new to Android programming.While trying to connect to PHP from my Android Client (WAMP) I get the following error

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 8383) after 10000ms
'I had searched for this type of error and had made all prescribed changes including Changing localhost to ipv address, changing the Timeout interval, configuring the httpd.conf file, still couldn't resolve.Pls find below the code, conf file changes and error log

Error Log:

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.8 (port 8383) after 10000ms
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:148)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.example.vijayar.phpconnect.MainActivity$AsyncRetrieve.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:80)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at com.example.vijayar.phpconnect.MainActivity$AsyncRetrieve.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:33)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-20 07:42:34.857 3370-3512/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-20 07:42:35.007 3370-3510/com.example.vijayar.phpconnect V/RenderScript: 0xb0f4b600 Launching thread(s), CPUs 3
```

Java Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 10000;
TextView textPHP;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textPHP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPHP);
    //Make call to AsyncRetrieve
    new AsyncRetrieve().execute();
}

private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    //this method will interact with UI, here display loading message
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    // This method does not interact with UI, You need to pass result to onPostExecute to display
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.8:8383/Checking/Checking.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    // this method will interact with UI, display result sent from doInBackground method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("Success! This message is from PHP")) {
            textPHP.setText(result.toString());
        }else{
            // you to understand error returned from doInBackground method
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
}

Manifest File
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

In Httpd.conf the following changes are made
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8383
Listen 0.0.0.0:8383
Listen [::0]:8383

<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
Options None
Allow from All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

PHP file -> Checking.Php

```
<?php 
      echo "Success! This message is from PHP";
?>
```

The PHP page works fine when invoked from browser.

Comment: do you add the permission？

Comment: Are you using an emulator for testing? If not can you access the page from the device browser?

Comment: before trying to access it from the Android code can you make sure that port is even reachable through telnet?

Comment: How to add permission and where? Kindly elaborate

Comment: I used both emulator and Android phone , result is same

Comment: Do you mean pinging it from command prompt? or ist different Telnet command?

Answer (score 3):

The problem looks like your Apache configuration might be listening on the wrong ip address. Android is trying to access the ip address `192.168.1.8:8383` and your Apache server needs to be on the same network with your Android device. I would recommend that you make sure your Android device is on the same network as the Apache server and that your server is setup to listen on the correct ip address that Android is trying to connect too.

Comment: Both devices , Android and laptop are connected to the same WiFi, should I still make any changes   Pls advise

Comment: You need to update Android to connect to the ip address that the Apache server is running on. What ip address is the Apache server listening on?

Comment: In httpd.conf I had added this line Listen 192.168.1.8:8383, (This is same IP address : port passed in URL )

Comment: Listen 192.168.1.8:8383
Listen 0.0.0.0:8383
Listen [::0]:8383

Comment: Timeout issue is resolved, this is what I did, I had added IPV4 to Listen command in httpd.conf file and disbaled temporarily the antivirus gateway(that was preventing request from hitting the server)

Answer (score 1):

Timeout issue is resolved, this is what I did, I had added IPV4 to Listen command in `httpd.conf` file and disabled temporarily the antivirus gateway (that was preventing request from hitting the server) –

Comment: I did what you say and didn't work for me. I have included in ```httpd.conf Listen 192.168.1.11:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080```. I don't know what you did about the antivirus gateway. Can you help me??